# Symfony 6.2 : The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine

After upgrading from Symfony 6.1 to 6.2, I got this error :

```
The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue.
```

To fix it, I've tried all solutions I could find :

- using `bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage` command
- using `bin/console bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` command
- changing/removing serverVersion on mysql url in .env (I'm on mysql 8)
- adding `storage` configuration in doctrine_migrations.yaml
- adding `check_database_platform: false` in doctrine_migrations.yaml

Nothing has worked so far...

I found that error is triggered by the doctrine_migration_versions table and specifically the plateform options.

Current table :

```
#_platformOptions: array:2 [▼
  "charset" => "utf8mb3"
  "collation" => "utf8_unicode_ci"
]
```

Expected table :

```
#_platformOptions: []
```

If I delete the doctrine_migration_versions table, I don't have the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem since the migration to Symfony 6.2.

One solution to solve the problem is to downgrade the doctrine migration to 3.5.2 :

`composer require doctrine/migrations:3.5.2`

(Issue on github https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/1302)